# What happens when I select a varchar column using number type?

Tags: mysql, implicit-conversion, varchar

I have a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `t` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The data in the table is:

```
mysql> select * from test;

+----------------------+
| t                    |
+----------------------+
| 12511023900355495873 |
| 12511023900355495872 |
| 12511023900355495874 |
+----------------------+
```

When I `select` from the table like this:

```
 select * from test where t = 12511023900355495873;
```

The result is:

```
+----------------------+
| t                    |
+----------------------+
| 12511023900355495873 |
| 12511023900355495872 |
| 12511023900355495874 |
+----------------------+
```

What implicit conversion happens when I use `number` to select a `varchar` column?

Answer (score 0):

The manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html    In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

so

```
drop table if exists t;

CREATE TABLE t (

t varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
t1 float

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into t values
( 12511023900355495873,12511023900355495873 ),
( 12511023900355495872,12511023900355495872 ),
( 12511023900355495874,12511023900355495874 );

select t.*,@t2 from t where t = 12511023900355495873;
```

results in

```
+----------------------+-----------+------+
| t                    | t1        | @t2  |
+----------------------+-----------+------+
| 12511023900355495873 | 1.2511e19 | NULL |
| 12511023900355495872 | 1.2511e19 | NULL |
| 12511023900355495874 | 1.2511e19 | NULL |
+----------------------+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that all float values in the column t1 are the same.

It goes without saying that you should avoid type conversion.